# Sign of a determinant based on sign conditions

Tags: matrix, inequalities

New user here. 
I want to sign a determinant, using known qualitative conditions on the components. any help appreciated. dummy example below. thanks.

```
mat = {{a, b}, {c, c^2}};
MatrixForm[%] ; 
det = FullSimplify[Det[mat]] ; 
Sign[det] | a > 0 & b > 0 & c < 0
```

Comment: Something like `FullSimplify[Sign[Det[{{a, b}, {c, c^2}}]], a > 0 && b > 0 && c < 0]`?

Comment: You could also try `Simplify[det > 0]` to see the conditions, which are `a c^2 > b c`.